# Doom-modeline seems to be breaking flycheck

Tags: flycheck, doom-modeline

I've tried to simplify the issue and taken elpy out of my init and stripped flycheck back to basic install using the following code in my init file:

```
(use-package flycheck
  :ensure t
  :init (global-flycheck-mode))
```

Which works on it's own. But when I try to add doom-modeline using the follow:

```
(use-package nerd-icons
  :ensure t)

(use-package doom-modeline
  :ensure t
  :init (doom-modeline-mode 1))
```

I get the error: `error while checking syntax automatically: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)` and no syntax checking is done. All my checkers look fine as well. Does anyone have idea what could be causing this issue? Or how I can go about finding out whats going wrong?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/doom/info

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: "*what do you mean?*" -- If you read that URL, you won't ask this question. Doom Modeline is just a package, written by @seagle0128. Whereas Doom Emacs is a configuration framework. I advise you to rollback to the last edit.

Comment: @shynur Note, that `doom-modeline` **is** integrated into `doom` but it can be used independently of `doom`. So, if Kai searches for people that can help he most likely finds them with the tag `doom`. Nevertheless, I introduced the more specific tag `doom-modeline`.

Comment: FYI: I cannot reproduce the problem starting from `emacs -Q` running `M-x package-initialze`, `M-x flycheck-mode`, `M-x doom-modeline-mode`, using Emacs version GNU Emacs 28.1.